# Regex to identify if a string contains backslash comma or caret

Tags: c#, regex

Pretty straightforward.. I'm new to regex and was wondering how I can perform something like this? Initially I went with:

```
if (Regex.IsMatch(par, "^[0-9a-zA-Z]+$"))
```

But it doesn't seem to be working.. I'm looking for something that specifically excludes backslash, comma and the caret.

I'm also looking for another expression to specifically check if dollar sign ($), comma (,), or period (.) exist in a string

Comment: Do you mean `@"^[^,\\^]*$"`? A whole string should not contain comma, caret and a backslash?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You seem to be looking for

```
@"^[^,\\^]*$"
```

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5E%5B%5E%2C%5C%5C%5E%5D*%24&i=abc123%7E!%23%24%26*)

**Details**:

- `^` - start of string
- `[^,\\^]*` - zero or more chars other than `,`,  `\` and `^`
- `$` - end of string.

Note that `[^...]` defines a [*negated character class*](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated)  that matches any chars but the ones specified in the class. Note that the second `^` inside the brackets is considered a literal caret (while the first one is a part of the negated character class construct).

If you do not allow an empty string, replace `*` (zero or more occurrences) with `+` (one or more occurrences).

To further create regexps like this, just put the chars into the negated character class remembering that `]`, `\`, `^` and `-` are better escaped to avoid confusion. The `$`, `*`, `(`, `)`, `+`, `|`, `{`, `?`, `.` lose their special meaning, and denote the literal symbols.

Comment: Awesome! I see how that works.. thanks for the breakdown! So if I wanted another expression to specifically check if dollar sign ($), comma (,), or period (.) exist in a string, would it be:
@"^[^$,.]*$"

Comment: To match a string that has no dollars, `,` and `.`, use `^[^$,.]*$`. If the chars you have are `]`, `^`, `-` and ``\``, use `^[^]^\\-]*$`. A hyphen at the end or start (or after a valid range and before/after a shorthand character class) does not have to be escaped. `^` does not have to be escaped if it is not the first char after `[`. ``\`` should always be escaped in character classes.